# use of ':=' fails in select in stored procedure due to variable definition

Tags: mysql, session-variables, assignment-operator

Why does the use of the assignment operator := fail to parse in this stored procedure (fragment)?    In the update statement, in the set median = [select expression], in the expression, the MySQL 5.6 parser reports the error, "[Check]...for the right syntax to use near ':= row + 1 as row, $vol as $vol from univ_members' ".

```
delimiter //
  CREATE PROCEDURE m()
BEGIN
  DECLARE row int;
  SELECT row := row + 1 AS row;
END //
delimiter ;
```

Running the select statement the mysql shell also fails, but says, 'row' is not a system variable or 'row' is not a column, depending on whether I try to define it with 'set'.

Do you know of a limitation in a stored procedure that prohibits this, or of such a bug in MySQL 5.6?  If so, is there a workaround?  Can you suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

So, after struggling like a man blinded by darkness, I defined the variable @row in the shell using 'set' (the shell's parser does not allow 'row') and it worked.  The parser however does not allow a variable defined in a stored procedure with 'declare' to begin with a '@', but, if defined with 'set', it works, it does allow it to be used as the left-hand value in the :=.

**So, it's an issue with variable definition.**  Evidently, only 'user variables', which must begin with a '@' and must be defined with 'set', can be assigned values with ':='.  (See [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html))

I find such a nuance that all variables don't share a common behavior when it comes to assignment non-intuitive and incredibly irritating.  Am I *still* missing something?